# By what mechanism do our nerves lengthen as people get taller?

Tags: human-biology, neurophysiology

How do nerves get longer as kids grow taller?  I searched for an answer but I can only find information on the formation of nerves in embryos.

Answer (score 3):

### They grow

Nerve axons can grow [rather quickly](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29666508) as long as the body of the cell is intact, quickly as in the mm/day range. This is also the basis of how nerves can regenerate.